# How do I short government bonds?

Tags: bonds, shorting-securities, government-bonds

Perhaps it's because I've just watched [The Big Short](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1596363), but I'm bearish on Italian Government bonds right now. How would I go about shorting government bonds?

Comment: I am not sure you should be doing that, considering you don't know how to short government bonds.

Comment: I looked for an inverse Italian bond etf, but didn't find anything. Shorting is a more advanced strategy than being long, are you sure you want to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had access to a broker that allows you to trade on Eurex, you could short euro-BTP futures, which are Italian treasury bond futures. However, if you're in the US, finding such a broker would be difficult and probably not worth the expense. If you're in Canada or another country that allows CFDs, there may be brokerages that let you trade euro-BTP CFDs.